# Spring Security Filters Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-authorization

I am relatively new to Srping Security Framework. During my learning period I have tried to implement a basic authentication security  feature for a private api endpoint `/private/**` . The application also contains a public api `/public/**` where not filters are applied and is accessible for everyone.
My code is presented below:

Employee.kt

```
data class Employee(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

SpringConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity) : SecurityFilterChain? {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authz ->
                authz
                    .antMatchers("/private/**").authenticated()
            }
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun users(): InMemoryUserDetailsManager {
        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            User.withUsername("john")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .authorities("read")
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

End points:
PublicEmployee.kt

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
class PublicEmployeeResource {

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    fun getEmployee(): ResponseEntity<Employee> {
        val employee =  Employee(name="John", age=42)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee)
    }
}
```

PrivateEmployee.kt

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/private")
class PrivateEmployeeResource {

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    fun getEmployee(principal: Principal): ResponseEntity<Employee> {
        val employee =  Employee(name="John", age=42)
        println("Principal is ${principal}")
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee)
    }
```

}

When I am using `.formLogin(withDefaults())` for authentication, I get the below picture and I can pass the user and password as stated `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`.

[image]

However if I change the autnetication to  `httpBasic()` I do get the response from Employee object without any authentication.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Also I have read that WebConfigurerAdapter() is going to be deprectated. How I could setup multiple filters for specific url patterns in then ?

Comment: I think you'll configure a FilterChainProxy, details found here, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Comment: Tried "incognito mode"? (..devtools + browser session..;)

Comment: Why it works with incognito ?

Comment: Incognito appears (just) as a "new session" to the server... (i assumed devtools, since it can "hot reload" code changes preserving http/security session) ..alternatively you could have logged out or cleared your browser cookies/cache...